# CSS Tables, Divs, Spanning... too much confusion out there

Tags: css, layout, positioning

I'm finding a large amount of conflicting information regarding this layout. Some sources say use a table, others use a div.

http://www.bootply.com/mDIcRVOq8J

Basically, a square on both ends and two stacked rectangles between them.

I have most of what I want but I cannot figure out the inner div positioning as noted in Bootply.

What I Have: 
[image]

What I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Solution:
http://www.bootply.com/o3m5A8BKJK

Comment: I have no idea what your question is.

Comment: It helps if you open the bootply

Comment: Post the relevant code in your question please.

Comment: This question loses all value to future visitors should bootply ever be inaccessible or just go away. Code questions should always have the code in the question, with examples like jsFiddles, jsbins, bootplys, etc. as a supplement, never the only source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you need, add vertical-align:top to the doc-tile-content, remove display: table-row from the .row class, and add display:block to the inner content divs.

Comment: Blam, you nailed it. Thank you for your awesome help.